# Implementing a filter with an LDI integrator why this phase jumps

Tags: filter, sampling, switched-capacitor

So I have a continuous time filter that I implemented in discrete time using an LDI Integrator. This what I obtained for the filter phase:

[image]

In green there is the phase for the continuous time filter and in black for the discrete one. What are the weird phase jumps? Is it because of sampling?

EDIT:
I'm implementing a 4th order Bessel filter using an MF10 and here is my schematics:
[image]

Comment: Are you sampling at 150 kHz? (error: I meant 250 kHz).

Comment: @Andyaka 250 kHz!

Comment: Oops I meant 250 kHz (fixed). Yes, sampling does this.

Comment: @Andyaka is there anything else in particular because I'm using a LDI integrator (implementing this in a MF10 IC).

Comment: Well, it's pretty coincidental with the switching frequency (and harmonics) so draw your own conclusions.

Comment: I know LDI have no phase error on low frequency (only the spectrum repetition for higher frequencies due to the sampling frequency). There is a magnitude error, but it is only visible for higher frequencies since it is something lix x/sin(x) so it's practically 1 for lower frequencies. I guess that's it, right?

Comment: You should edit your question with the schematic, and put the fact that it's an MF10 in the body of the question while you're at it.  It won't change the quality of my answer, but it'll help any *real* switched-cap filter experts out there.

Comment: @TimWescott Thank you for your input, I will edit my question!

Answer (score 1):

> What are the weird phase jumps?

Weird phase jumps, because you're using a time-varying system.  I suspect the little hiccoughs at \$\frac{F_s}{2} + nF_s\$ has to do specifically with the switched-cap nature of the filter; the big excursions at \$nF_s\$ are because the circuit is a periodically time-varying one.

If you felt up to an afternoon's worth of math you could look up [someone's class notes](https://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/%7Eee247/fa06/lectures/L11_f06.pdf) on switched-cap filters, and grab someone's datasheet for the MF10 (TI's is good, but I can't get a direct link).  Then work out the actual time-domain equations -- they'll be periodic enough that at some point you can go to the z-domain, with decorations for what happens due to FET channel resistance, and due to the fact that the LDI output commences \$\frac{1}{2}\$ clock intervals after the input starts affecting the filter. (you'd have to make outright guesses about what the MF10's channel resistance and capacitances actually are).

I *think* that the little hiccough in phase at \$125\mathrm{Hz}\$ is either because the chip's clock phases aren't exactly lined up right, or because there's some lag between the actual chip's response and that of an ideal chip with no channel (or other) resistance.

> Is it because of sampling?

I really hate the use of the term "sampling" for switched-capacitor filters, because the channel resistance of the switches is going to interact with the capacitances and make it not-quite-sampled.  Which is why I'm being careful to say "periodically time varying" rather than "sampled".  I'm probably being too picky.

But yes, it's due to the periodically time varying, almost-sampled nature of the circuit.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I don't know if you saw other question I posted about simulating the filter and getting some rather odd values. Do you have any input you can give regarding that?